# Route "onEnter" is loading data after loading the route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using redux with react-router. I am also making one API call to load the data before loading routes. Technically my data should be load first then my route should be loading. However I found that it first load the route then it load the data from API. Following is code details.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {ReduxRouter} from "redux-react-router";
import {Route} from "react-router"

import createBrowserHistory from "history/lib/createBrowserHistory"
import configureStore from './store';

import App from "./containers/App";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Countries from "./components/Countries";
import {fetchData} from './actions/actions';

const history = new createBrowserHistory();
const store = configureStore();

function loadData() {
  store.dispatch(fetchData('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all'))
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReduxRouter>
      <Route history={history}>
        <Route component={App}>
          <Route path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/countries' component={Countries} onEnter={loadData} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </ReduxRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

store.js

```
import { compose , createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./../reducers";
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { routerStateReducer, reduxReactRouter } from 'redux-react-router';
import createHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

//Create app store
const createAppStore = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware),
  reduxReactRouter({createHistory})
)(createStore);

export default function configureStore( initialState) {
  const store = createAppStore(rootReducer, initialState);
  return store;
}
```

reducer.js

```
import  * as types from "./../actions/actionTypes";
import  {combineReducers} from "redux";
import  {routerStateReducer} from "redux-react-router";

function exampleReducer (state = {isLoading : false, data : [], error:false}, action = null) {

  switch (action.type ) {
    case types.RECV_ERROR :
      return Object.assign({}, {isLoading : false, data: action.data, error: true});
    case types.REQ_DATA :
      return Object.assign({}, {isLoading : false, error: false});
    case types.RECV_DATA :
      console.log("Data receive, return immutable store ")
      return Object.assign({}, {isLoading : false, data: action.data, error: false});
    default:
      return state;
  }

}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  router: routerStateReducer,
  example: exampleReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

action.js

```
import * as types from "./actionTypes";
import axios from 'axios';

function requestData() {
  return {type: types.REQ_DATA}
};
function receiveData(json) {
  return{
    type: types.RECV_DATA,
    data: json
  }
};

export function fetchData(url) {

  return function(dispatch) {
    //dispatch request for request data to start the spinner
    dispatch(requestData());
    //Now make the real API call to get the data
    return axios( {
      url: url,
      timeout: 20000,
      method: 'get',
      responseType: 'json'
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log("Data is loaded");
      //Data is receive, now call function to aware this
      dispatch(receiveData(response.data));
    }).catch(function(response){
      console.error("Some error happened");
    });
  }

}
```

Countries.js

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import Country from "./Country";

@connect(state => ({data: state.example.data}))
export default class Countries extends  React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    const {data} = this.props;
    console.log("Countries component is loading... data "+ data);

    console.log("Countries  this.props "+ JSON.stringify(this.props));
    return (<div className='container'>
      <table className='table table-bordered table-striped'>
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Capital</th>
          <th>Population</th>
          <th>Domain</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        { data ? data.map(country => { return (<Country key={country.name} country={country} />)}): null}

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complexity in your case comes from the fact that the data-loading is an **asynchronous** operation.

If you want the onEnter function to wait for the loaded data before triggering the route transition, you should use the "callback" argument (as stated in [react-router's doc](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback)).

But to know when the data has been loaded, you should also listen to the changes of your redux state in your onEnter function. You could write something like this:

```
function loadData(nextState, replace, callback) {
    let unsubscribe;
    function onStateChanged() {
        const state = store.getState();
        if (state.example.data) {
            unsubscribe();
            callback();  // data is loaded: trigger the route transition
        }
    }
    unsubscribe = store.subscribe(onStateChanged);
    store.dispatch(fetchData('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all'));
}
```

Rather complicated, isn't it?!

You should try to avoid this pattern, for several reasons:

- it uses an additional, low-level, subscription to the store, which increases complexity in the app
- data-loading is asynchronous, and can take some time; since you block the process in the onEnter function, then nothing appears on screen and it's bad UX

That's why you'd better load your data in the componentDidMount method of a component, in a non-blocking way. Before loaded data is received, simply define an initial state (without data) for the component.

You'll find useful standard patterns in [Redux's real-world example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world), which features react-router.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful.

Comment: Well, to be fair, you don’t need to wait for Redux store in this way. `fetchData()` already returns a Promise, so you can `store.dispatch(fetchData(...)).then(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use componentDidMount or componentWillMount in your `<App/>` component.
And you can fetch data before routing.